# pthreads_create(...) executed function - pointer confusion

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers, pthreads, function-pointers

so i'm diving into multithreading in c via POSIX pthreads but i do really struggle with the general concept of pointers and their referencing and dereferencing mechanisms. 
One of the parameters in
`pthread_create(...,pthread_attr_t *attr,...)` 
is a function pointer.

This function is usually declared like this:

`void *thr_func(void *arg){
  thread_data_t *data = (thread_data_t *)arg;
  ...
}`

thr_func is a function pointer, so usually i use a function pointer to reference to an existing, implemented function via &, e.g.:

`thr_func = &thr_func_impl;`

while the arguments of thr_func are also pointers dereferenced for example via * to retrieve the values they are pointing to.

What I don't understand is the following:

- when i create a thread, why do i just give the function name in `pthread_create(...,thr_func,...)` instead of its address so that it can be used, e.g.: `pthread_create(...,&thr_func,...)` or is this done by `pthread_create()` already ?
- How do i have to understand this part: 
  `thread_data_t *data = (thread_data_t *)arg;` okay i want to dereference a
  structure of type thread_data called data via `thread_data_t *data = ...` . 
  Shouldn't i do it this way:
  `thread_data_t *data;
  data = &arg; /* now * on data ,e.g.: *data == struct-data (dereferencing) gives the struct data and data without * just gives the structs start address */`

-> I cannot really follow the things happening inside:

`void *thr_func(void *arg){
  thread_data_t *data = (thread_data_t *)arg;
  ...
}`

I'd be glad if somebody had a good explanation, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Passing the function name as a parameter is equivalent to passing its address using the `&` operator. I.e. `pthread_create(...,thr_func,...)` and `pthread_create(...,&thr_func,...)` are interchangeable. This has nothing to do with pthreads, it is a language construct.
2. `arg` is a pointer of type `void`. In order to cast it to a pointer of type `thread_data_t` you should do `(thread_data_t *)arg`. By using `thread_data_t *data = &arg` you are attributing the address of `arg` itself to `data`, not the address `arg` is pointing to.

Consider the following:

```
int my_int = 7;
void *my_void_ptr = &my_int;

int *my_int_ptr = (int *)my_void_ptr; // Just a cast, points to my_int
printf("%d", *my_int_ptr);            // 7
int *my_int_ptr2 = &my_void_ptr;      // int pointer to the address of my_void_ptr, issues a warning
printf("%d", *my_int_ptr2 );          // The address of my_void_ptr as an integer
```

Finally, pthreads stands for POSIX threads, so "POSIX pthreads" is redundant.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it. I didn't know that the function name & the address-operator applied to it are interchangeable, but it makes sense since the only thing we're interested in might be the start position of a function in the address space of the program. In your explanation `void *my_void_ptr = &my_int` simply declares a void pointer to my_int.

Comment: [Continuation of @Leo's previous comment:] Since this pointer has not yet been assigned a type, we need to cast it using: `...= (int *) my_void_ptr;` & assign it to f.e. `int *my__int_ptr = (int *) my_void_ptr;` in order to use it inside the function which is also just a pointer now pointing to the same address as `my_void_ptr`. Now having had declared `my_int_ptr` as a pointer, see: `int *my_int_ptr =...;`, we can simply dereference and get its value via `....*my_int_ptr;` and get the address of the stored value (`my_int`/7 in your example) by `...&(*my_int_ptr);`.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, a function will naturally decay to a pointer to itself, similar to the way that arrays decays to a pointer to its first element.

So if you have a function

```
void *thr_fun(void *arg) { ... }
```

then you can pass a pointer to it using either `&thr_fun` which is the explicit and (some would say) "correct" way. The other is to use plain `thr_fun` as it will decay to `&thr_fun` anyway. So in C it's really a question about style and personal preference.

---

For your second question, remember that `void *` is a generic pointer that can point to anything but it doesn't have any explicit type. Therefore you can't dereference it (since a dereferenced `void *` would have the type `void`).

That's the reason you need to cast it.

And no you should *not* get the address of the pointer, since that will give you a pointer *to the pointer*.

Comment: And to counter the "correct" way, I'd say that the *best way* is to use the shortest construct allowed by the language which is still correct.